# Filter in gmail by member of google group

Tags: gmail, email-filter, google-groups

Scenario:

`frank@example.com` and `alice@example.com` belong to google group `hr@example.com`. Both of them send important memos to the whole company.

Until today, I had been able to search for important HR messages by filtering in gmail with this filter:

```
from:frank@example.com OR from:alice@example.com
```

Problem is, there is a new member of HR `bob@example.com`. He also sends mail to all employees, he also belongs to group `hr@example.com`.

I hate maintaining my filters. I am looking for a filter that will allow me to find email from anyone that belongs to group `hr@example.com`. I was looking for something like this:

```
from:hr@example.com
```

This doesn't work though, I get zero results with this filter.

**Does anybody know if there is a way to filter email by members of google groups in gmail?**

Note: I am aware that they could in theory send email using as sender the group `hr@example.com`. They don't however, and I am not campaigning for them to change.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: seems that in gmail lingo a google group is also known as a mailing list, so the question applies to also mailing lists

Comment: I tried also `list:hr@example.com` and didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found so far is - if you have permissions to view the membership of the group in question - to make a static filter with the search operator *OR*, like *from:email1@domain.ext OR from:email2@domain.ext* etc. for all the members of the group.

Sadly, this is cumbersome and does not update with changes in group membership in e.g. an email filter rule.

Hopefully, someone has a better solution using maybe Google Apps Script or Google updates its GMail search to traverse list/group memberships.

Sources:
https://groups.google.com/g/gmail-power-users/c/aHnG4O2yVSI/m/BXFexjiCCwAJ
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

PS: You could add some regex like "(?=>)(.*?)(?<=<)" and replace all instances with " OR from:" in for example VS Code to get a list with only email addresses except some characters to manually edit in the beginning and end of the copied group member list text.